Getting your cat into toy feeders
I schedule feed our cat two full meals and then a small snack before bed just for my own sanity. I was giving this snack right after putting our toddler to sleep but then he got in the habit of it and would cry loudly whenever I gave him his snack which then woke up our toddler :/ So I switch his snack time to before we put our toddler to bed. At first our cat was a bit confused and assumed now he gets 2 snacks but I thought this behavior would stop... it did not... not even after 2 months. So onto the cat pages I went when I found a video about the same night time noises as our cat ritually does.
m,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,- says our cat who just stepped on the keyboard
The video suggested puzzle feeders and toy feeders. Since his snack is dry I quickly bought a cute acorn shaped toy feeder that he simply has to bat around to get his snacks out. He loves rolling balls around at night so I thought he would like this... he has yet to figure this simple toy out. Strange because he is really smart and I have trained him easily to do several other things. I thought putting some cat nip in it might help but then he just laid next to it happily.
Any ideas how to make him use this toy feeder? I would love this since then he can both play and get his dry snacks at the same time giving him 2 things at once.
PS. Our cat is weird and does NOT like any wet snacks and pretty much only wants his kibble. I have tried several other dried snacks and he won't eat them. Same with his wet food, he only eats the chunky pate wet food when mixed with a bit of his dried kibble so he seems to have a texture preference.

Possible duplicate of https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/teaching-cat-to-use-feeding-toy

Have you demonstrated it to him by shaking/batting some treats out of it?
Cat treats rather than just ordinary kibble may motivate him more.
Different cats figure out different puzzles at different speeds; what comes naturally for a given cat isn't just a matter of intelligence. Hazel picked up the sliding-covers treat puzzle much more quickly than Harry did, but Harry understood swinging doors much better (Hazel tried to pull with the wrong paw for a very long time). If a puzzle isn't being solved, try another and/or practice patience until the cat finds the necessary insight. Obvious isn't.

I have tried several dried and wet cat treats over the year that I have had him but he has rejected everything so far :/ I'm not sure what to try anymore. But last night I decided to take the top off of the toy (which has a textured inside) and put his kibble in that. He played with it the first time last night and ate all the kibble inside. So now I'm thinking to keep it this way for a few weeks until switching to the bottom half of the toy and then later on closing it up once again.

Well I played out my experiment and it worked. For a week now our cat has been playing around figuring out how to get every last treat out. Now he is a pro and knows exactly what to do and seems to really enjoy it too :)
